# Bash: split string into triplets and quartets

Tags: bash

How can I split a contiguous string without a delimiter into groups of 3 characters from `LSB` to `Msb` and store in array?

For example, `bcdefghijhk` should become:

```
bc def ghi jhk   
b cdef fghi ijhk
```

Using pure bash string manipulation.
Reversing a string is not an option as order needs to be preserved eg. triplet jhk cannot be khj

Comment: What are `LSB` and `Msb`? What is the exact logic that should be followed here? Why aren't you splitting to `bcd efg hij hk`? And does this really need to be _pure_ bash? You can't use capture groups in things like `${var//old/new}`, can't we also use tools like `sed` or `cut`?

Comment: LSB and MSB are the least/most significant bit/byte, but that nomenclature doesn't really make sense with a string. You could do that with the string slice expansion `${var:pos:num}`, but I wonder if this is something that would be better done in another programming language.

Comment: related: [printf, awk ... How to format a number with space to the thousands](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/416011)

Comment: Why would reversing the string not be an option? It would be easier to work on the reversed string and then reverse it again to get the final result. E.g. `rev | fold -w 3 | rev | tac | paste -s -`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way I found to split the string the way you asked.  I've written it as a Bash subroutine (aka function) because I had a feeling you would incorporate it into your own scripts that way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

number=bcdefghijhk
chunk=2

number_parts=()  # global variable

function slice_number {
  local num="$1"
  local chk="$2"

  local len=${#num}
  local pos=0
  local chk_first=$(( len % chk ))

  # the first chunk is smaller when the number length
  # is not an exact multiple of chunk-size
  if [[ $chk_first -gt 0 ]]; then
    number_parts[${#number_parts[@]}]="${num:$pos:$chk_first}"
    pos=$(( pos + chk_first ))
  fi

  # collect the rest of the number as full-size chunks
  while (( (pos + chk) <= len )); do
    number_parts[${#number_parts[@]}]="${num:$pos:$chk}"
    pos=$(( pos + chk ))
  done
}

# call the slicing routine
slice_number "${number}" ${chunk}

# now $number_parts[] has the sliced up number
printf '%s ' "${number_parts[@]}"
echo
```

I called the string a "number" because you described it as having MSB and LSB, but this manuipulates it as a string.  I called the size of the groups you requested (3 or 4) the "chunk" size.

At first the task seemed very difficult since the rightmost end of the string must be a full-size chunk and the leftmost end the partial chunk.  Most string-wise parsing wants to do the reverse.  Then I realized that the total string length modulo the chunk size would give the reduced length of that first (leftmost) chunk, and the rest of the chunks would be exactly the chunk size.  The first chunk can be a special case and the rest are an easy loop, advancing the starting position for the next slice through the string.

The routine saves the chunks in an array, with the 0 (first) element in the array holding the leftmost chunk of the string, and the last element in the array holding the rightmost chunk.  The last line of my script shows an example of printing out the chunks with space separators (though there's a trailing space on the end), which is the kind of output you indicated.  The code can be modified to assemble a string rather than an array.

The array is populated with a technique I use a lot but don't see often elsewhere.  In zero-based arrays, the number of array elements is, by coincidence, the index of the next element past the end of the array.  I.e., "pushing" a new element onto the end of the array will populate that index.  It makes the array assignment look complex, but it works.

Finally, this example subroutine doesn't perform any checks on the given string or chunk-size arguments.  There should be something to handle if the chunk-size is 0 or a negative number, or has non-digit characters; The subroutine should take special action if the chunk-size is larger than or equal to the length of the string.  Also handle if the string is empty.

Comment: you can also append to an array with `arr+=( new items )` (it's different if the array is sparse: `+=` adds a new element that's one higher than the greatest existing one, while `"${#arr[@]}"` might be in use in a sparse array.)

Answer (score 0):

If switching from `bash` to `zsh` is an option:

```
$ set -o extendedglob
$ string=bcdefghijhk
$ print -r -- ${(j[])${(Oas[])${${(j[])${(Oas[])string}}//(#m)???/$MATCH }}}
bc def ghi jhk
$ print -r -- ${(j[])${(Oas[])${${(j[])${(Oas[])string}}//(#m)????/$MATCH }}}
bcd efgh ijhk
```

Where:

- `s[]` splits on *nothing* meaning the string is split into its character constituents.
- `Oa` reverse `a`rray `O`rder.
- `j[]` joins array elements with nothing, so those 3 operators combined reverse a string.
- `${var//pattern/replacement}` usual ksh93 substitution operator
- `(#m)` (needs `extendedglob`) causes the match to be stored in `$MATCH`.

Note that if the string length is an exact multiple of the nibbles, you'll get a leading space (which you could trim with `${result# }`).

See also [that other approach in another related Q&A here](/a/140393).

Answer (score 0):

This could be understood as (mainly) a math problem.

It is possible to extract some length of characters (single bytes in bash) with the general syntax `${str:start:length}`. Both start and length are numbers. Numbers that define the start position and how many characters to address.

Given an string `str` and a `width` number, the first chunk of characters should be of length `echo $(( ${#str} % w ))`. That is the part of the string that could not be divided into chunks of 3 characters.

For the str supplied and one of the requested widths (3), we get:

```bash
$ str='bcdefghijhk'
$ w=3
$ echo "$(( ${#str}%w ))"
2
```

Lets call this value `o` (offset) and then we can do:

```bash
$ str='bcdefghijhk'; w=3; o=$(( ${#str}%w ))
$ for (( i=o-w ; i<=${#str} ; i+=w )); do 
    start="$(( i>0?i:0 ))";                # if the index is negative, use 0
    part="$(( i<0 ? o : w ))";             # use offset or w
    echo "${str:start:part}";              # extract one part.
  done

bc
def
ghi
jhk
```

Yes, the first index may be negative, that might be understood as the equivalent to the offset value in modular arithmetic.

Of course, that doesn't print the string in the format requested, and it would be better if the whole process could be defined in a function. With both those changes, and a lot of reductions, we can write:

```bash
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash --

split()
    {      
        local str=$2 w=$1 o i arr IFS=" ";
        local o=$((${#str}%w));
        arr=();
        for (( i=(o==0?0:o-w) ; i<${#str} ; i+=w )); do
            if (( i<0 )); then
                arr+=("${str:0:o}");
                continue;
            fi
            arr+=("${str:i:w}")
        done;
        printf "%s\n" "${arr[*]}";
    }
split "${@}"

$ chmod u+x tst.sh

$ ./tst.sh 3 'bcdefghijhk'
bc def ghi jhk

$ ./tst.sh 4 'bcdefghijhk'
bcd efgh ijhk
```